# How could I use this function for calculating CHECKSUM

Tags: c#, checksum

I'm trying to calculate checksum for serial communication. so I made a byte array for databuffer.
I don't know how to use this byte array of databuffer to this fuction.
because this function's parameter type is byte pointer. 
How do I use this function?

```
byte[] arrayForChecksum // for databuffer

// calculating a checksum for C#
public unsafe static ushort CalcCRC(byte * pDataBuffer, uint usDataLen)
{
        byte nTemp;
        ushort wCRCWord = 0xFFFF;

        while ((usDataLen--) != 0)
        {
            nTemp = (byte)(wCRCWord ^*pDataBuffer++);
            wCRCWord >>= 8;
            wCRCWord ^= TABLE_CRCVALUE[nTemp];
        }

        return wCRCWord;
}


// original code in C
unsigned short CalcCRC(unsigned char* pDataBuffer, unsigned long usDataLen)
{       
    unsigned char nTemp;
    unsigned short wCRCWord = 0xFFFF;

    while (usDataLen--)
   {
        nTemp = wCRCWord ^ *(pDataBuffer++);
        wCRCWord >>= 8;
        wCRCWord ^= TABLE_CRCVALUE[nTemp];
    }

    return wCRCWord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use checksum for anything. For example, you can convert the text you will get from the database to byte array and calculate the checksum value.

```
public class Crc16
{
    private const ushort polynomial = 0xA001;
    private static readonly ushort[] refTable = new ushort[256];

    public Crc16()
    {
        GenerateReferenceTable();
    }

    private void GenerateReferenceTable()
    {
        ushort value;
        ushort temp;

        for (ushort i = 0; i < refTable.Length; ++i)
        {
            value = 0;
            temp = i;

            for (byte j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
            {
                if (((value ^ temp) & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    value = (ushort)((value >> 1) ^ polynomial);
                }
                else
                {
                    value >>= 1;
                }

                temp >>= 1;
            }

            refTable[i] = value;
        }
    }

    public ushort Calculate(byte[] bytes)
    { 
        ushort crc = 0; 

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
        {
            byte index = (byte)(crc ^ bytes[i]);
            crc = (ushort)((crc >> 8) ^ refTable[index]);
        } 

        return crc;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 204, 120 }; 
Crc16 crc16 = new Crc16();
ushort checksum = crc16.Calculate(bytes);


string data = "Calculate Checksum";
byte[] bytesFromString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
ushort checksumForString = crc16.Calculate(bytesFromString);
```

You can also check out my project.

https://github.com/hidayetcolkusu/ChecksumManager